# Blazor Webassembly Azure AD authentication hosted in Azure return 404 after signing

Tags: azure, docker, azure-active-directory, dockerfile, blazor-webassembly

I have Blazor Webassembly client app that works from `VS studio` perfect, I deployed in using `docker` after I get authenticated it returns 404, I have deployed to Azure and I got the same error.

The return path is set correctly in Azure AD.

My docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./clientApp/. ./clientApp/

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /source/clientApp/
RUN dotnet publish -c release

FROM nginx AS runtime

COPY --from=publish /source/clientApp/bin/release/netstandard2.1/publish/wwwroot/. /usr/share/nginx/html/.
ADD ./clientApp/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

the error

```
http://localhost:8080/authentication/login-callback#id_token= <tokenvalue>" // 404 not found nginx 1.19.10
```

what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The issuer is related to misconfiguration of Nginx see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0 **Nginx** section.

I update my Nginx config file by adding:

```
...
 location / {
            root      /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
...
```

Nginx will redirect traffic whenever cant find resource matching the request to 'index.html'.